# -ms-high-contrast css media selector in other browsers

Tags: html, css, accessibility

The style of my web app is for the most part directed at users who can operate a mouse. Some focusable elements don't look so good when focused (clicked on) so these elements have [custom or no outlining](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/28/stop-messing-with-the-browsers-default-focus-outline/#why-do-people-want-it-removed). Some inputs are bootstrap inputs so their focus is dictated by bootstrap.

When a user is visually disabled (not totally blind but has trouble to see) I would like to emphasize the focused elements. Usually these users have some sort of high contrast on and this can be detected in IE:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  /* All high contrast styling rules */
  *:focus {
    /*outline-color: red !important;*/
    outline-width: 5px !important;
    outline-style: solid !important;
  }
}
```

How would I go about implementing this in other browsers and would this be supported on other operating systems?

Maybe we can give the user an option for a different theme of the site but I'd rather have this automatically done based on the user's settings in the Operating System.